# URL forwarding JSF

Tags: jsf, web, redirect

I have a JSP page which is named as erSelection.jsp. But, at the deployment in the configuration file it is stored as ERSelection.jsp as a result page not found error is found. Is there a way in JSF we can redirect the URL http://localhost:8080/Test/ERSelection.faces to erSelection.faces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just renaming the physical file is really not an option, your best bet is to either create a custom [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which does that

```
if (request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/ERSelection.faces")) {
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/erSelection.faces");
    // You may want to do a 301 instead with a Location header.
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

or to grab a more customizeable URL rewrite filter which does that by a simple configuration file, such as the [Tuckey's URLRewriteFilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution worked for me. I am a regular visitor of your blog.